# Is it valid to correct for std::vector iterator invalidation in the following way?

Tags: c++, c++11

Using C++11 or higher, suppose we store an iterator pointing to an element in a vector:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto it = v.begin() + 2;  // it points to 3
```

Now, erasing an element before or including the pointed-to element will invalidate `it`. I am assuming erasing an element does not cause memory reallocation (maybe incorrectly?), so would it then be valid and well-defined behavior to correct `it` as follows:

```
--it;
v.erase(v.begin());
// it still points to 3 in all cases?
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/3dzrcW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

From cppreference

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the `end()` iterator.

`v.erase(v.begin());` has invalidated all iterators. Using `it` has undefined behaviour.

There is no way to "correct for" iterator invalidation. Once an iterator object is invalid, the *only* thing you can do with it is assign a valid iterator value to it.

Comment: I have yet to see an iterator that is not usable and does not point to the right element in practice. Since an iterator is a glorified pointer it makes sense to me, assuming no memory reallocation occurs.

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel *so far*. Undefined behaviour is **most dangerous** when it *currently* does what you expect.

Comment: Usually it can work but it is undefined behavior. The memory where the iterator points to is not owned by you anymore and may be used by another part of your program.@TonvandenHeuvel

Comment: @Caleth, what I do not understand is why it would be undefined behavior, given that no memory reallocation occurs (as far as I understand from reading the standard only insertion might cause reallocation)...

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel here's a case of your exact code leading to errors: https://godbolt.org/z/M7vjMv (Your original example too: https://godbolt.org/z/8W7hsr)

Comment: @Artyer, interesting thanks, I did not know about `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`.

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel -- it's undefined behavior because the standard says it is. Undefined behavior means only that the standard doesn't tell you what your program does. It does not mean that bad things must happen. Sometimes the code will do exactly what you expect, until you're giving a demonstration to your most important client, at which time it will fail spectacularly.

Comment: @Zaiborg, I think the memory is still owned by us because the vector will not change its capacity?

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel doesn't matter. The standard says they are invalidated. That's why the debug iterators can be modified by the erase to throw on everything